# Program works on one computer but not another

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, driver

I have this really weird problem when working with my java selenium project. When I am at work I program and run the code I write with no problems, but when I come home, write code, and try to compile it in Eclipse it gives me:

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

When I bring the code from home into my work computer it compiles and works. So I know that isn't the problem.

PROBLEM: how can I get this program to run on my computer from home? This is what driver I am using (IE). The part where it crashes is whenever I call an xPath in any method or even in main. Would love some help thanks.

```
public static WebDriver driver(){
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");

     DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

     dc.setCapability("EnableNativeEvents", false);          //Disable native events

     dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);  // Issue with downloading the report

     dc.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting",true);

     WebDriver thing = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);

     thing.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     thing.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));  //Set zoom level to 100%

     return thing;
}
```

Comment: You state that the error happens whenever you use an XPath, but I see nothing using an XPath in your code above.  Usually a "NoSuchWindow" type of error means that either an expected browser tab did not open or the browser itself did not open.  Does it open the browser at all?  In my opinion the IE webbrowser driver is a lot more complicated and buggy than chrome or firefox drivers.

Comment: Thanks Bill. The IE window opens itself then with a get(URL). After using the get I use my xPath("...") to find what page link I want to click on. I have looked around and have seen people use a lot of firefox and chrome. Not much on IE. Might just switch to firefox.

Comment: I would try to put a debug point in the program and step through to try to find which line is causing the exception.  Feel free to show the example of your first findelement command that uses the XPath, there might be something there that you missed (we all do that sometimes)

Comment: @BillHileman Allow me to disagree with you on `IE webbrowser driver is a lot more complicated and buggy than chrome or firefox drivers` :) IMO, the implementation of Web Applications will definitely vary from Browser to Browser. At times, IE Browser behaves a bit different compared to chrome or firefox browser but not complicated. Afterall `Bug` is the word for which Developer/Tester teams are formed :)

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks for letting know about the Chrome driver. works 100000 time better and faster. only problem is that it doesn't close the driver when program ends. but that's nitpicking.

Comment: I've noticed that as well.  If you check your task manager, you'll see an instance of the driver for each time you run a test.  There's probably a code example out there somewhere on how to stop the process, but it's also a minor problem to me as well, so I ignore it.  They can always be killed manually through the task manager if need be.

Answer (score 0):

A few basic information about the solution:

1. To execute your Selenium/Java code either you need to put the code within `public static void main(String[] args) {}` or using TestNG you need to put the code within a method like `public void test1() {}` along with `@Test` Annotation. Both are missing in your code.
2. There is no use of this line `public static WebDriver driver` as moving forward you have already `WebDriver thing`
3. `public static void main(String[] args) {}` or `public void test1() {}` won't return anything, so omit `return thing;`
4. You have ignored the zoom settings `dc.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting",true);` if your zoom settings are not set to `100%` moving forward you may face unintended errors & exceptions.
5. Setting the zoom level is out-of-scope for Selinium so your line `thing.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));` will never get executed.
6. Here is your working code with some simple tweaks for you using `public static void main(String[] args) {}` for your reference:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        dc.setCapability("EnableNativeEvents", false);          //Disable native events
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);  // Issue with downloading the report
        dc.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting",true);
        WebDriver thing = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);
        thing.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: 1. I made this method as an easy way to call the driver in each of my class calls in main that take in webdrivers like `duck(driver())` and so on.

Comment: @Sleepyfalcon So from rest of the Answer did your Question got addressed?

Comment: 2. that is just making the webdriver to work with IE. I'm stuck on the part where it just doesn't like me using xPaths on this computer.                                3. if you mean by `public static WebDriver driver() {}` it returns a WebDriver that it used in classes i call in main.                                           4. probably. This is my first time really working with Selenium at an internship ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: I like your help and all to help fix my problem but the real problem lies in that it crashes when i call an xPath in. i thought it had something to do with screen size. not sure how that could effect an xPath though. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I think rather returning the WebDriver you should be looking for the best practices either by putting your code within main() or under @test Annotation. Let me know if this answers your question. Thanks